# sqlite Format text with variable value

Tags: sqlite

I want to do the equivalent of this java code in sqlite for the error message in a RAISE(ABORT, 'message')

```
String location = //initialize string
String output = String.format("Error: Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references location %s that is not found in database.", location);
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SightingLocationError
  BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NEW.LOCATION NOT IN FEATURES
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Error: Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references location'|| CAST(NEW.LOCATION AS TEXT) ||
 'that is not found in the database.');
END;
```

I've also tried it without the cast to text and with parenthesis around the entire message part, and those methods didn't work either.
What would be the proper way to format the error message so that it will display the name of the location that can't be inserted because it's not in the FEATURE table?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to reinvent `FOREIGN KEY` with trigger.

I suggest to use:

```
CREATE TABLE FEATURES (ID INT PRIMARY KEY /*rest of columns*/);

CREATE TABLE SIGHTINGS(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, LOCATION INT,
             FOREIGN KEY (LOCATION) REFERENCES FEATURES(id));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=9470bdacd5fa29923c7f2d06e30af504)**

Comment: this is actually for an assignment on triggers with a database that's already been created. The assignment said we had to create a trigger to abort the insertion of a row to the SIGHTINGS table if the LOCATION attribute was not present in the FEATURES table and display an error message. I can post the schema if needed.